# How can I program the cpu to randomly press buttons?

Tags: matlab, tic-tac-toe, matlab-app-designer

I am creating a game in matlab app designer in which a player plays against the computer opponent. I want to code the CPU to press a button at random when it is its turn. For example, in TicTacToe the player plays against another player but in this case, the opponent is the CPU. The CPU is able to click buttons at random for example if there are 9 buttons it will press on any of those 9 randomly providing it has not been pressed already. I am not sure how to program this any help would be highly appreciated.

I have tried to use the callback function but do not know how to program the cpu to randomly press buttons.

Comment: Think about this: what happens when a button is pressed? The callback function is triggered. So you do not actually have to make the CPU press the button; you only need the callback function to be called, so just call it.

Comment: If you need input to this callback function, just do `randi(9)` to get a random integer between 1 and 9 you can use.

Comment: When the human has made its move you again call the press button function and give it a random integer (or whatever you want to use)

Comment: @StewieGriffin I have tried doing this but I don't think I am doing it correctly: if app.pl_move == 2
              n = randi(9)
              app.Button_(n).Text = "X";
              app.Button_(n).Enable = "off";
              app.pl_move = 1;
           end

Comment: `if app.pl_move == 2
              n = randi(9)
              app.Button_(n).Text = "X";
              app.Button_(n).Enable = "off";
              app.pl_move = 1;
           end`

Comment: @ShaobinJiang `if app.pl_move == 2               n = randi(9)               app.Button_(n).Text = "X";               app.Button_(n).Enable = "off";               app.pl_move = 1;            end`

Answer (score 0):

On second thought, this is not as simple as triggering the callback function, because you have to let the AI know when to "press" the button also. So, the part about notifying the AI should be in the callback function as well:

```matlab
function ButtonPushed(app, event)
    % Get the button that triggered the callback function
    btn = event.Source;

    btn.Text = 'X';
    btn.Enable = 'off';

    % Now, notify the AI to make its move
    AI_btn = app.Button_(randi(9));

    % Obviously there are better ways to do this
    % I will leave it for your own improvisation
    while ~isequal(AI_btn.Enable, 'on')
        % If the button is already pressed...
        AI_btn = app.Button_(randi(9));
    end

    AI_btn.Text = 'X';
    AI_btn.Enable = 'off';
end
```